# Need help to reduce the execution time for the code below

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Below code compares 1500 rows with about 14 columns . It takes around 30 min to execute them . Is there any way , I could reduce the code by altering the code below .I like to get all your expert opinion. 
The code makes the following function
 Run through all records in Old Sheet.
if found in NEW sheet  , Do nothing
if not found in NEW sheet , Delete it from OLD sheet

```
Option Explicit

Function UpdateOLD() As Long
'     This Sub will do the Following Update
'     Run through all records in OLD
'        if found in NEW  ---> Do nothing
'        if not found in NEW ----> Delete it from OLD.
'
Dim WSO As Worksheet
Dim WSN As Worksheet
Dim MaxRowO As Long, MaxRowN As Long, I As Long, J As Long, lDel As Long
Dim sJob As String, sOps As String, sFirstAddress As String
Dim cCell As Range
Dim bNotFound As Boolean


'---> Disable Events
With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'---> Set Variables
Set WSO = Sheets("Steps")
Set WSN = Sheets("Interface")
MaxRowO = WSO.Range("A" & WSO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
MaxRowN = WSN.Range("C" & WSN.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
WSO.Range("N2:N" & MaxRowO).ClearContents

'---> Loop thruough all rows in sheet New
For I = MaxRowO To 2 Step -1
    bNotFound = False
    sJob = WSO.Cells(I, "B")
    sOps = WSO.Cells(I, "C")
    Set cCell = WSN.Range("D6:D" & MaxRowN).Find(what:=sJob, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    If Not cCell Is Nothing Then
        bNotFound = True
        sFirstAddress = cCell.Address
        Do
            '---> Check to See if Ops if found for that Job
            If WSN.Cells(cCell.Row, "E") = sOps Then
                bNotFound = False
                Exit Do
            End If
            Set cCell = WSN.Range("D6:D" & MaxRowN).FindNext(cCell)
        Loop While Not cCell Is Nothing And cCell.Address <> sFirstAddress
    Else
        bNotFound = True
    End If

    '---> Del Record from OLD if Not Found
    If bNotFound Then
        WSO.Range(I & ":" & I).EntireRow.Delete
        'WSO.Range("N" & I) = sJob & " " & sOps & " Deleted as NOT found in NEW"
        lDel = lDel + 1
    End If


Next I

'---> Enable Events
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

UpdateOLD = lDel

End Function
```

Comment: Hello John, this question is best suited for codereview. They will help you, but on first eye if your problem is the performance. I'd work with arrays. Two choices, 1 array and empty the rows where you need, to later paste it back to the sheet and remove duplicates (so the blank rows will get all deleted but 1). Or 1 array with the original data and a second one with the output data to paste it back.

Comment: Hi , The code works absolutely fine . If you have better version to get the result . It will be great  .I could try them . The code basically runs through all the records in one sheet1 and compares with records with sheet2 . The records not found in sheet2 gets deleted in sheet1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO.Tried your code with around 2000 rows with around 10% mismatch and it take only few seconds. may be the file have some other issues. However one way to speed up (about 1/2 the time taken in my trial) is to add all the `bNotFound` cells in a union of range and delete the `EntireRow` of the range in one shot after finishing the loop.

Changes in Code:

```
Dim Rng As Range    'Add in  Declare section 
'
'
'
'
For I = 2 To MaxRowO   'No need to loop backward
'
'
'
'
    If bNotFound Then                       ' Only add to Union of ranges
        If Rng Is Nothing Then
        Set Rng = WSO.Range("A" & I)
        Else
        Set Rng = Union(Rng, WSO.Range("A" & I))
        lDel = lDel + 1
        End If
    End If
Next I

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then Rng.EntireRow.Delete       ' delete in one shot
```